# Cascade updates after sqlalchemy "after_update" event

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to cascade updates after a model has been updated:

```
event.listens_for(Task, "after_update")
def propagate_status(mapper, connection, target):
    object = target.object
    if object.is_finished():
        object.status = COMPLETED
```

The issue is that I can't seem to get the object status commited to the actual db. I can tell that the status does get set because I have a listener attached to object.status.

I have tried calling commit() on the object but that results in:

```
ResourceClosedError: This transaction is closed
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this? Should I use the connection object directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who find this later on. I was able to successfully use the connection directly:

```
@event.listens_for(Task, "after_update")
def propagate_status(mapper, connection, target):
    obj_table = Object.__table__
    object = target.object
    if object.is_finished():
        connection.execute(
                scan_table.update().
                where(object_table.c.id == object.id).
                values(status=COMPLETED)
            )
```

If there is a more elegant way I am all for it.

Answer (score 1):

When calling `after_update` the session is in the flush state. So you won't be able to commit any changes with that session. Another way is to create a new session inside the `after_update` event handler

```
@event.listens_for(Task, "after_update")
def propagate_status(mapper, connection, target):
    obj_table = Object.__table__
    object = target.object
    if object.is_finished():
        session = db.create_scoped_session() # or any other way
        session.query(Object).filter(Object.id == target.id).update({"status": COMPLETED})
        session.commit()
```